# Angular Xhr post requests to Asp.Net Web API results in parameter is null

Tags: ajax, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I’ve created an ASP.Net API Controller to which I’m trying to make a POST request with Angular. The request reaches my controller method, but the parameter value is null.

My Angular code:

```
$http({ method: 'POST', url: '/api/Contents', data: "value=foobar", headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).
    success(function(data) {
                }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

I’ve also tried with json (Json is what I want in the end):

```
$http({ method: 'POST', url: '/api/Contents', data: { "foo": "bar", "foo2": "bar2" }, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }).
    success(function(data) {
                }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

My (very simple) Controller method looks like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    //But Value is NULL!!!!!!
}
```

Below are some values from my request headers cut out from Chrome (the ones I thought could be interesting:

- Request Method: POST
- Status Code: 204 No Content
- Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
- Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
- value: foobar
- Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
- X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: '/api/Contents', 
    data: "=foobar", 
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).success(function(data) {

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

Notice the `=foobar` data parameter. You should not specify a parameter name in this case. Yeah, I know, don't ask.

You can read more about [`how model binding in the Web API works`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx). And if you are like me and find this absolutely insane, you might consider using [`ServiceStack`](http://www.servicestack.net/) instead.

Alternatively you could use a view model:

```
public class ContentsModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take the view model as parameter:

```
public void Post(ContentsModel model)
{
}
```

Now you can send a normal JSON request:

```
$http({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: '/api/Contents', 
    data: JSON.stringify({ "value": "the value" }), 
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } 
}).success(function(data) {

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

Also notice how if you want to send JSON you need to use the `JSON.stringify` method to transform the javascript object into a JSON string.

Comment: I'm using the view model method above, but my request data is an array of view model objects, which Web Api is set to accept as a List<Object>. When the content headers are set to form-urlencoded and the data hits the service from Angular, I get an empty object with Count=0. If content headers are set to app/json, I get OPTIONS method not allowed error. If I send the data from Fiddler, content type is set to Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8 automatically and the service accepts it just fine. Any idea how to deal with that?